# Error with conditional types: "Type '"mello"' is not assignable to type 'T extends "hello" ? "mello" : "wat"'."

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am learning about generics + conditional types and have this function:

```
function x<T extends 'hello' | 'world'>(arg: T): T extends 'hello' ? 'mello' : 'wat' {
  console.log(arg)
  if (arg === 'hello') {
    return 'mello'
  }
  return 'wat'
}
```

This code doesn't compile, I get red squigglys under `return 'mello'` and `return 'wat'`:

- `Type '"mello"' is not assignable to type 'T extends "hello" ? "mello" : "wat"'.(2322)`
- `Type '"wat"' is not assignable to type 'T extends "hello" ? "mello" : "wat"'.(2322)`

According to my understanding, this should work though: I am defining a function that can have either of two return types: either the literal `'mello'` or the literal `'wat'`. Which of these two types the return type of the function is depends on whether the input type `T` extends the type `hello`.

In my function code, I then return '`mello`' if the input `arg` is `hello`. If no, it's `'wat'`.

How can I implement the function with these type definitions such that the TS compiler is happy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is not that smart to handle such cases. I would suggest using [function overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) instead.

It is type-safe, and if you try to return the wrong thing, the compiler will complain:

```
function x(arg: "hello"): "mello";
function x(arg: "world"): "wat";

function x<T extends "hello" | "world">(arg: T) {
  if (arg === "hello") {
    return "mello";
  }
  return "wat";
}
```